# How to create partition on remote tablespace in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I'm a noob in Oracle, is it possible to partition a table to remote server using db link? is it possible at all?

I'm trying something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  TestID       integer           not null,
  Name       varchar2(20)      not null
)
PARTITION BY LIST (TestID)
 (PARTITION testPart1 VALUES (1)
TABLESPACE tbspc1,
 PARTITION testPart2 VALUES (2)
TABLESPACE tbspc2@RemoteServer);
```

thank you

Comment: Ok, why would you want to do this?

Comment: actually I'm not sure. My problem is that in uni I've got an assignment to design and implement distributed system but lectures are so poor that I don't know where to start. We need to implement system for a company which has 2 branches and these branches should use distributed DB. some data should be common, e.g. Customer table, and some internal data which should not be distributed. I don't know where to start.

Comment: what technology are you allowed to use?

Comment: design makes sense, implement... wow... can the common data be updated in the branches... both branches? You'll want to make sure that your Surrogate keys don't clash... the prof might want you to use Guids but they are slow and can clash...use sequences. one branch all start at 1 step 2 and the other branch all start at 2 step 2. You could do that on all tables, even ones he says aren't shared. there's no harm and is ready to merge if they change their mind.

Comment: the both branch can update the common data, you're into a situation called multi-master and that always requires the business to define rules for managing conflict. ie. you walk into a branch and your wife walks into the other branch... both of you update your address (cuz you moved) but one of you got it a little bit different/wrong. Which one should win = be the right record.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm using Oracle and APEX forms. So u suggest to have two databases of the same structure but with different data on 2 servers and use different sequences as PKs. Ok, I thought about it, but is it a wise design? I doesn't seem like distributed database, it looks like 2 different DBs with the same structure. I'm trying to figure out best practices and make it professionaly.

Comment: then you tell me. What is a distributed database in the context of two branch offices. How many instances does that take? 1, 2, more? Tell me the count you want to use.

Comment: I don't know, if I knew, I probably would not ask this questions here. t

Comment: The problem is that they ask us to design and implement distributed database without any explanation how to do it, on lectures we had just silly theory about relational algebra, predicates and partitioning. No examples, no case studies. So I'm trying to find out from people who have some experience in DBs how can I implement it in practice.

Answer (score 4):

No, that will not work. You're confusing an instance with a database.

A database is the physical storage of the data and metadata. The number of disks you use and the location of the disks is up for management. You can put indexes one place, data in another; you can put some data on local drives and some on mounted drives. That's a database.

An Instance is the memory structures and computer processes which access a database and make it possible to query it, write to it, update it, etc.

When you say @DB_LINK... you're saying "That set of memory and cpu processes".

When you say Tablespace, you're saying "On those files, on those disks"

If you want to store data on the same drives that your @dblink is storing data then mount that drive and build a new tablespace there.

If you're trying to OPEN the database with more than one instance, that's called RAC and it's bit over your head. <-- I say this because you have to have these concepts mastered before you'd ever consider RAC.

Comment: Ok, thanks Stephanie, where should i start if i need to have distibuted DB?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say that something is impossible, but based on the syntax diagram for CREATE TABLE this doesn't look possible.  For the select statement you can see that the dblink syntax (@ dblink): http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2126073   But for partitioning storage there is no such remote syntax:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#CJADDEEH

Comment: ok, thanks, can u advise something conserning my question's comment?

Comment: You can make a local tablespace use remote files as Stephanie suggested, or make entire tables remote. But most likely you need to redefine "distributed". Managing a single database is difficult, splitting up your data will be complicated and slow. Creating tables and data is easy; making sure you never, ever lose data is the difficult part. This requires logging, monitoring, multiple backups, disaster plans, etc. If a company wants better performance and redundancy then technologies like RAC and data guard are what you should look into.  Make one branch the primary and the other the standby.

Comment: no, this is not a real company, it's my coursework and i need to design distributed DB, difficulties don't matter. The problem is that I don't know where to start. Shall i have a db on one server and have a views on another created via dblink? but this case doesn't provide any distribution at all. this is my level, just basics. I need a kick.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following would be a reasonable starting point:

1. Have a database at the "home office" to contain the common data.
2. Have a "local" database at each branch to store branch-specific data, with links to the "home office" database to access the common data.
3. To help eliminate the "single point of failure" which could occur if the central database was to go down or communications were to be lost, you might try replicating the common data from the central database to the branch databases so that each branch has a complete copy of the common data which could be updated on some sort of regular schedule.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: What is the best way to have a local database? shall I use snapshots or something else?

Comment: I'd expect that each branch would have a local installation of the database software (same product as is used at the "home office") so that replication, etc, could work as seamlessly as possible.  Then replicate the 'core' data to each branch.  Central office works live against the central database, each branch runs against their own database.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Oracle and reading about materialized vies at the moment for replicating necessary data. But how can I make synchronization using it, e.g. if data was changed in branch, can I syncronize it with global DB and how to do it?

Comment: Try http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Advanced_Replication_FAQ and  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/data-integration/default-159085.html which may help out.